# Problem simulating LMP8645 current sense amplfiier in LTspice

Tags: amplifier, ltspice, current-sensing

Basically the problem i am getting is that the output offset voltage is extremely large (58mv)

here is the datasheet for the amp: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmp8645hv.pdf

on page 9 it shows the relation ship between the Vout and Vsense and as you can see the output offset voltage is ~1mV

here is my schematic + simulation : [image: https://imgur.com/a/mnvAHNS]

the blue line is the output voltage Vout, green line is the voltage across R1 (the sense resistor), the x axis is the voltage of V2.

I expect the blue and green lines to match since the gain is set to 1 but as you can see there is a large difference between them which doesnt match the datasheet.

I should note that the circuit behaves as expected when VR1 becomes large, as can be seen here:

[image]

I tried a variety of supply voltages too, including +-5, +-2, 5 to GND, 10 to GND, 4 to GND , as well as a variety of gain resistors like 5k, 10k, 20k, and i get the same results.

the spice model was gotten from this page : http://www.ti.com/product/LMP8645/toolssoftware

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please change your pic so it shows the simulation command, or a netlist,  I have no idea if your scanning V2 (I *assume* your scanning it from 0 to 100V but who really knows?) You ought to use horizontal screens instead of vertical.

Comment: I would start by testing the model and use parameters from their datasheet to see if the model is valid, sometimes companies make crap spice models

Comment: Also try adding some parasitics to your supplies and sources, minimal, as to not influence your circuit, such as `Rser=1m`, and/or `Cpar=1m` for supplies, or similar. Sometimes, that's all it takes. If not, even if the model isn't bad, there may be cases when the implementation simply doesn't go according to reality. This is the SPICE world, after all.

Comment: I tried adding parasitics and it didnt work. could the fact that the model is listed as a PSPICE model be the problem, considering i am using LTSPICE, not PSPICE?